# it's possible do embed Microsoft Teams meeting on Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, microsoft-teams, x-frame-options

MS teams provides a url of a video meeting to embed in external places, like a inframe on my website?

I tried to added like this:

```
<iframe src="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_N2E3MzMxYzUtZjEyNi00NzM1LTgzZGUtNzVkMmRkN2QwM2M2%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%22f65eecb0-375c-4019-8d96-6395afd428b4%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22044239fc-d173-426f-b356-e08c6e7cb025%22%7d" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

But it gave an error:

```
Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to display a online meeting of teams on my site?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: You cannot embed the Teams meeting UI in your website. Every teams meeting should either be opened inside Teams app or in Teams browser.

Answer (score 1):

Currently embedding Teams meetings or chats in a webpage is not possible.
You can give an upvote to the corresponding <s>[uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33244858-allow-html-embedding-of-teams-channels)</s> request or use a [3rd party product](https://www.socialintents.com/embed-teams.html).